# Statements in php

Tags: php, if-statement

```
if($getstatus->num_rows != 0 && $getstatusarr = $getstatus->fetch_assoc() && $getstatusarr["Type"] != $data["type"])
    echo "error"
else
    ...
```

*first code will not work, to make works this way, see [Nin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12798982/1532730) post*

Is it possible to make the code easily?

Also I can do it like this:

```
if($getstatus->num_rows != 0)
    $getstatusarr = $getstatus->fetch_assoc();
    if($getstatusarr["Type"] != $data["type"]) {
        echo "error"
        $error = true;
    }
if(!$error) {
    ...
}
```

by ellipsis I have too many lines of code :)

**added:**
also I can do in this way:

```
if($getstatus->num_rows != 0) {
    $getstatusarr = $getstatus->fetch_assoc();
    if($getstatusarr["Type"] != $data["type"]) {
        echo "error";
        goto skip;
        }
}
... // some code which I need not to execute if $getstatusarr["Type"] != $data["type"] are true
skip:
// another code which will execute in all cases
```

Comment: $getstatusarr = $getstatus->fetch_assoc() OR $getstatusarr ==$getstatus->fetch_assoc()  ??

Comment: Why do you have too many lines of code?

Comment: @swapnesh no, I make it for next statement
    $getstatusarr["Type"] != $data["type"]

Comment: @itachi I don't use frameworks, here's only mysqli with oop

Comment: @Nin ? it's strange question :D it's not neccessory to show here

Comment: Well, I don't understand your question. If you can't tell me why you need less lines of code, I can't give an answer.

Comment: @Nin I mean if there a way to make the code better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, don't use goto: :)

Whether you put all the if's on one line or on several lines is mostly a personal preference.

Too many lines with if will make the code harder to read but putting it all on one line also makes it difficult to read and difficult to debug (error on line 12 can mean many things then). If you're using a debugger like xdebug or Zend debug then having multiple lines to step over is also easier.

So find a way in between this.

I would do it like this, since then you also check if fetch_assoc() returned a result:

```
if($getstatus->num_rows != 0 && $getstatusarr = $getstatus->fetch_assoc())
    if($getstatusarr["Type"] != $data["type"]) {
        echo "error"
        $error = true;
    }
if(!$error) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: thx, made an edit in my question, so I thought there is a way to do it with another way, but kinda another way is not exist.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view is always best to unwrap statements and clean the code as much as you can, maybe someone later on will have to read what you did and he will have a hard time doing that.

Also you cannot assign new variables in a if statement like that:

```
$error = false;
if($getstatus->num_rows)
    $getstatusarr = $getstatus->fetch_assoc();
    if($getstatusarr["Type"] != $data["type"]) {
        $error = array('type' => 'invalid type');
    }
}

if($error) {
    // do something with $error array
}
```

Comment: instead of echo "error", I show more details, I just didn't write it in question.

Comment: then you should use like I said, make an array out of `$error` and the loop in that array.

Comment: your example like exceptions in oop, sometimes it's usable code, but what if I have only this error? then I think my way is better :D But the question is not about that...